# how to check if Xiaomi autostart button is enabled?

Tags: android

Is there anyway to check if the autostart is enabled on my app? I want to check it first before I display the dialog for autostart. I have an issue in Xioami

Comment: follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366231/how-to-check-miui-autostart-permission-programatically

Comment: @NileshRathod there is no solution in that link. It does not check if the autostart is enabled

Comment: @Mobi10 have you got any solution to it??

Comment: Hi Any solution?