# MiUi widget programming issues workaround?

Tags: android, widget, miui

I'm programming apps and widgets. Recently I was reported that widget programmed by me stopped worked after a minute or so. All of those issues had one similar thing: MiUi. One device was Redmi, another one was Huawei, but both had MiUi. I was looking all my code around and failed to reproduce error(widget not replying at all on button click etc). But after I noticed, that all those issues occured on MiUi only, I found this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F1QBqmgf7bg .

As I don't own any of deviced having MiUi myself, I wanted to ask, if any of developers have any known workaround on widget coding level? Is it possible to request that some weird permission from app itself or some manifest tune-ups?

Any help would be very much appriciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check MIUI autostart permission programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366231/how-to-check-miui-autostart-permission-programatically)

Answer (score 0):

I had no Xioami phone reports yet. But Redmi and Huawei seem to have something similar that kills widget.

I am looking for more complex solution for those.

Redmi has also MiUi thing and Huawei some Emui thing that also kills widget