# Battery usage settings, allow app running in background programmatically

Tags: android

In android Settings-> App Management -> App(Selected) -> Battery usage.

We find 3 options :
[image]

How we can programmatically enable option 1 ( run in background), if we can't, how to redirect user to this page.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a [mega thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122098785) on this at google's issue tracker. There is no simple way to change this, every OEM that has these types of fine control has it's own activity you need to point.

[This site](https://dontkillmyapp.com/) has a list of OEM's that does this. [This old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366231/how-to-check-miui-autostart-permission-programmatically) has a lot of OEM's and intents you may use. And [this library](https://github.com/judemanutd/AutoStarter) is a collection of these auto starters, so you may redirect the user to this screen.