# How to Allow notification sound programmatically in Xiomi devices

Tags: android, android-notifications

Notification sound settings always disable in Xiomi devices. Check below image.

I want to enable sound programatically.  Found similar stackoverflow questions but nothing helped.

**Device** : Redmi Note 5 pro, Redmi Note 9 pro

**OS** : MIUI 11 , MIUI 12

Note: But it works fine in all other devices. Problem only in Xiomi devices

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code which works for all other devices except for the above mentioned?

Comment: Hi, You found a solution this problem ?

Comment: @SerkanKOCAMAN no. If you found pls answer

Comment: No, i guess this unpossible.

Comment: @SerkanKOCAMAN ohh ok thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same kind of issue 2 months ago, due to restrictions by Xiaomi it has become a lot harder, basically you have to have your app running without restriction in save battery settings and to bring the user to autostart where he will have to click on the toggle button to add your app.

#### Prompt the user to disable battery optimization for your app:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
   {
       String packageName = "com.example.myapp";
       PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);        
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            Intent i = new Intent();
            if (!powerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
                i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
                i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> For an app to use this, it also must hold the [Manifest.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS)

---

#### You also have to prompt the user to add your app to autostart ([original credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366231/how-to-check-miui-autostart-permission-programmatically)) :

```java
String manufacturer = "xiaomi";
if (manufacturer.equalsIgnoreCase(android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER)) {
    //this will open auto start screen where user can enable permission for your app
    Intent intent1 = new Intent();
    intent1.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
    startActivity(intent1);
}
```

It should now be working, let me know if it helped!

Comment: Sorry. My problem is "Allow Sound". This answer doesn't solve the my problem. Verified.

Comment: @Ranjithkumar did you solve it?

Comment: @OliverD no. Not solved yet. Client forgot this bug :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX` in new NotificationChannel

Comment: Max available importance is NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH