# how to check Programmatically AutoStart Permission is Enable or disable on android studio

Tags: java, android

How to check Programmatically if the "AutoStart" permission is Enable or disable on android studio ?

In This Image :
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "AutoStart Permission"?

Comment: i think RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED Permission AutoStart  Permission to app to allow auto boot like alarm automatic started on seted time

Comment: @shubhamsoni , i hope my post answers your question ?

Comment: `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` cannot be disabled in ordinary Android. If there is some device manufacturer that allows it to be disabled, you would need to contact that manufacturer or do research specific to that manufacturer.

Comment: RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED is only think i request for AutoStart permission this permission specific customized android os like vivo, oppo, etc on available

Answer (score 2):

> There's no way to find out whether the Auto-start option is enabled or not

Source : [How to programmatically enable auto start and floating window permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383983/how-to-programmatically-enable-auto-start-and-floating-window-permissions)

> For now it's not possible.
>
> As it's completely depend on their operating system API's and
> customisation. Even developers have requested for this on XIOMI's
> official forums but there is no response from there side.
>
> Till now even i am finding an answer to this question but nothing
> helped me.

Source : [How to check MIUI autostart permission programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366231/how-to-check-miui-autostart-permission-programmatically)

Comment: thanks for reply  but this one i implemented  so i requested how to check enable or disable because if i not  check is enable or disable so mostly user every time missed to this permission so thats is required.