# How to open Auto start permission settings in Realme devices

Tags: android, android-intent, background-service

what is the Intent ComponentName to ask Auto start permission in Realme devices.I'm not able to open auto start permission via intent in Realme devices.

OS version:- ColorOS version V12, Android 12 , realme UI version V3.0.

For Example if you want to ask auto start permission in xiaomi devices this is the ComponentName com.miui.securitycenter and com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity as showed in below code example.My question is what are the packages name to open or ComponentName to open Auto Start setting in Realme devices via Intent?

```
val intent = Intent()
 intent.component = ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity")
 val list = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                context.packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
                    intent,
                    PackageManager.ResolveInfoFlags.of(PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY.toLong())
                )
            } else {
                context.packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
                    intent,
                    PackageManager.GET_META_DATA
                )
            }
            Log.e("tag", "list: " + list.size)
            if (list.size > 0) {
                context.startActivity(intent)
            }
```

**Expected Output:**

This below i want to open via intent in Realme devices:

[image]

I'm trying this packages com.oplus.battery , com.oplus.powermanager.fuelgaue.PowerControlActivity

As Showed in Below code:-

```
  val intent = Intent()
    intent.component = ComponentName("com.oplus.battery", "com.oplus.powermanager.fuelgaue.PowerControlActivity")
                context.startActivity(intent)
// Added this in Android Manifest
     <uses-permission       android:name="oplus.permission.OPLUS_COMPONENT_SAFE"/>
```

but this error is coming :-

Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=com.oplus.battery/com.oplus.powermanager.fuelgaue.PowerControlActivity mCallingUid=10430 } from ProcessRecord{85fc956 14770:com.claimbuild/u0a430} (pid=14770, uid=10430) not exported from uid 1000

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to check Programmatically AutoStart Permission is Enable or disable on android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70405204/how-to-check-programmatically-autostart-permission-is-enable-or-disable-on-andro)

Comment: @ΓDΛ this do not answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

For **Oppo**/**Vivo**/**Realme**/**OnePlus** — based on ColorOS

```
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.startupapp.StartupAppListActivity")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.FakeActivity")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startupapp.StartupAppListActivity")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startupmanager.StartupAppListActivity")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safe", "com.coloros.safe.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safe", "com.coloros.safe.permission.startupapp.StartupAppListActivity")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safe", "com.coloros.safe.permission.startupmanager.StartupAppListActivity")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startsettings")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startupapp.startupmanager")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startupmanager.startupActivity")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.startupapp.startupmanager")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.privacypermissionsentry.PermissionTopActivity.Startupmanager")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.privacypermissionsentry.PermissionTopActivity")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.FakeActivity")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.iqoo.secure", "com.iqoo.secure.ui.phoneoptimize.AddWhiteListActivity")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.iqoo.secure", "com.iqoo.secure.ui.phoneoptimize.BgStartUpManager")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager", "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"))
```

I think you need this

```
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"))
```

[source](https://medium.com/@Lakshya_Punhani/background-services-running-forever-in-android-part-3-e49389214e6e)

Comment: thanks for rely but this did not work.

Comment: ComponentName("com.oplus.battery", "com.oplus.powermanager.fuelgaue.PowerControlActivity") i have try this but this error is coming :

Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=com.oplus.battery/com.oplus.powermanager.fuelgaue.PowerControlActivity mCallingUid=10430 } from ProcessRecord{85fc956 14770:com.claimbuild/u0a430} (pid=14770, uid=10430) not exported from uid 1000

Comment: Judging by the fact that you received this error, Realme has limited access to obtain settings. I think in this case you should display a notification to the user with text explaining why this setting is needed and ask him to manually set this permission.

Comment: did you try only one intent or all those listed in the answer?

Comment: i have try all intent that you specific.

Comment: yes you are right i have to show video how to grant auto start permissions that is the only way.