# How to check programmatically that user has enable the AutoStart permission or not ? (in MI devices)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am able to to go setting & comeback from it but didn't get if user has enable the AutoStart or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check MIUI autostart permission programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366231/how-to-check-miui-autostart-permission-programmatically)

Comment: Yes @SergeiKozelko, I got the library to check the autostart permission state on MIUI 10, 11 and 12.

https://github.com/XomaDev/MIUI-autostart